# How can I filter rows in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have a JTable with many strings in it. I have created a textbox for user entry, above the table. I want a row filter which can remove the rows having strings entered by the user in the text box. Please help me out for this.

Comment: do you want to display only rows with the text or to not display rows with the text?

Comment: If you are allowed, you could use GlazedLists. It has samples about auto-completion and table filtering.

Answer (score 12):

from here:
[sorting and filtering](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

> In the following example code, you
>   explicitly create a sorter object so
>   you can later use it to specify a
>   filter:
>
> ```
> MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
> sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
> table = new JTable(model);
> table.setRowSorter(sorter);
> ```
>
> Then you filter based on the current
>   value of a text field:
>
> ```
> private void newFilter() {
>     RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
>     //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
>     try {
>         rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(),0);
>     } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
>         return;
>     }
>     sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This few line solution seems to work:

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel())); 
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(jTextField1.getText()));

    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter` which will use the default row sorter/filter of the `JTable`

Answer (score 1):

To pick up the comment from kd304, you could use [GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/). There you'll use a FilterList as the input for your JTable, and the FilterList will take care of the rest.