# show specific rows in java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have a Java Table and `TableModel.each row(element)` has a ID. I want to show specific IDs . How can filter this elements? Selected IDs can be changed.

For example:

```
public class L {
int id;
String name;
String family;
}

//----

private static final String[] columnNames = { "name","family"};
private static final Class[] columnClasses = {class.String.class,String.Class};
private Vector<L> list = Vector<L>();

list.add(new L(1,"A","b"));
.
.
.
list.add(new L(100,"AB","aa");
```

I want to show elements with this IDs, for example {1 39 45 55 22}.

How can filter these IDs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable

Comment: are you sure that you overrode getColumnClass by using Class[] columnClasses = {Integer.class,String.Class};, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable compilable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with RowFilter and TableRowSorter:

```
final int[] ids = new int[]{1, 39, 45, 55, 22};
RowFilter<Object, Object> filter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>() {
  public boolean include(Entry entry) {
    L currentObject = (L) (entry.getValue(0));
    for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        if(currentObject.getId()==ids[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
yourTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Tested, it works for me

Hope this helps

Comment: @nasir You are asking to filter your rows by ID, so this code will always work, no matter how many fields you add to your class

Comment: I add "family" field and remove ID from table but ID exist in "L" class.
entry get columns table.ID isn't column table.and when i run the program it cannot cast String(entry.getValue(0)) to "L" class. :(

Comment: `list.add(new L(1,"A","b"));` Adds a `L` object to your table, if `entry.getValue(0)` is a String it means that you didn't post the real code.

Comment: thanks Harlandraka

I change my code to ==>

    private static final String[] columnNames =   {"ID","name","family"};
    private static final Class[] columnClasses = {Long.class,String.class,String.Class};

and then remove ID column in myTable then use your code.
 
    myTable.removeColumn(myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));

thanks again.