# How can delete/hide the mid row(5)th row before it listed in jtable

Tags: java, swing

Here i have an 1-10 row is listed in jtable i want to delete/hide the 5th row before it listed in jtable.

i set the rowheight but it affected the cellselection.Is there any way to hide/delete the row without affected the normal flow code?

If i remove the row it will throws ArrayIndexoutofBoundException.

in my project executed means one gui open in that gui listed the some string. In here we can add the more string via Add Button on popup Button

Here what i need is i have to hide the particular string. That string is placed on 1st row.
i need to hide the string from end user.

now u hope understand.

Comment: your question is not clear to me. Especially `And i set the hide it will hide the remaining row(list). if user add the additional rows(list) via add button that list also hided. so we can't do that.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the JTable [row filtering support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) in order to hide certain rows without deleting them from the model. Also see this: [How can I filter rows in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate rows in the table by calling the `removeRow()` method.  If you want to just hide it instead of elimintaing it you need to customize the JTable's model to meet your specs on what to display.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

using [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) with `JTable` you should be able to use `model.removeRow(int row)` function to remove A row from `JTable`. There is no way to hide a row *`based on index`* as much as i know. However, If you need to hide and re-show mechanism you need to save the row prior to delete it and Save the `removedRow` in a `ArrayList` to re-use them.. Something as follows:

```
 List<Vector>deletedRows = new ArrayList<>();
 Vector removingRow = (Vector) model.getDataVector().get(5);
 deletedRows.add(removingRow);
 model.removeRow(5);
```