# JTable fill data with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcombobox

I have a frame with table,combobox, i want to fill the table with data from database by combobox, but if i use with itemlistener i dont see the table, without itemlistener and `String sql="select * from Arlista"` then i see my table with data
(combob=combobox)

```
combob.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        tesztvalt=(combob.getSelectedItem()).toString();

        if (e.getItem().equals(tesztvalt))
        {
            try {

                Class.forName( driver );
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url );
                String sql="select * from "+tesztvalt+"";
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int columns = md.getColumnCount();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                    {
                        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                    }
                    data.addElement( row );

                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println( e );
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
            {
                public Class getColumnClass(int column)
                {
                    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                    {
                        Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                        if (o != null)
                        {
                            return o.getClass();
                        }
                    }
                    return Object.class;
                }
            };
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM "+tesztvalt+""; 

PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) 
{
    tabla.setModel(model);
}
```

You have a couple of problems:

1. You are using the `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. Your code may work (I'm not sure), but it does not take advantage of the features of the `PreparedStatement`.
2. The code that read the data from the ResultSet makes no sense because, well you aren't even reading any data from the ResultSet.

To use a PreparedStatement the code is something like:

```
String sql = "Select * from ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, tesztvalt );
stmt.executeQuery();
```

Now the PreparedStatement will build the SQL query with the proper delimiters so you don't need to worry about that.

Read the section from the JCBC tutorial on [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.

If you want to read all the data from a specific table, then check out the `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` code found in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). It shows how to build the query as well as how to access the column names and data.

Comment: thx, its helped, now i can populate table with data from database but how can i use my itemlistener part in this: [http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableFromDatabase.java](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableFromDatabase.java).

Comment: I don't understand the question, whether you use an ItemListener or ActionListener the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different way, but it is simple. When you select an item from the combo box, the table changes. It uses a table model:

```
//ComboTableTest.java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ComboTableTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3898736145211708745L;

    private JComboBox<String> combo;
    private MyTableModel tableModel;

    //constructor
    public ComboTableTest() {
        //set up frame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,175);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //create combo box
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
        combo.addActionListener(this);
        add(combo);

        //create table
        tableModel = new MyTableModel();
        final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == combo) {
            tableModel.setValueAt(0,0,(String)combo.getSelectedItem());
            tableModel.setValueAt(1,1,(String)combo.getSelectedItem());
            tableModel.setValueAt(2,2,(String)combo.getSelectedItem());
        }

    }


    /*** MAIN ***/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ComboTableTest frame = new ComboTableTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1359557492205432915L;

    private String[] columnNames = {"Col 1","Col 2","Col 3"};
    private Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}};

    public void setValueAt(int row, int col, String s) {
        data[row][col] = s;
        fireTableDataChanged(); //EDITED
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: tableModel.fireTableDataChanged(); must be called inside XxxTableModel, override that as notifier in XxxTableModels methods, more in API, this model hasn't, missing implemented the proper method for that

Comment: this is not use for me, cuz i want to call data from database

Comment: You can add your database calls in the ActionPerformed method above. I was just providing you an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most common approach is to have all the data in the JTable and use a filter which is based on the combobox selection.

In this question someone has done this based on a Text box. Changing for a combo would be simple.

[How can I filter rows in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable)

Or for a tutorial look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html
and select "Sorting and Filtering"