# Syntax Errror>>check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

I want after selection of device id from drop-down, other fields value automatically fetch into text fields.
But getting following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
    for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E80Y.jpg)

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String DeviceID=textField.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        String DeviceName=textField_1.getText();
        String SerialNumber=textField_2.getText();
        String ModelNumber=textField_3.getText();
        String Make=textField_4.getText();
        try 
        {
            Connection con=DB.getConnection();
            Statement ps=con.createStatement();

             ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("Select DeviceID,DeviceName,SerialNumber,ModelNumber,Make FROM deviceadd WHERE DeviceID =?");
             if(rs.next())
             {
            String ID = rs.getString("DeviceName");
            textField_1.setText(ID);
            String FN = rs.getString("SerialNumber");
            textField_2.setText(FN);
            String LN = rs.getString("ModelNumber");
            textField_3.setText(LN);
            String Des = rs.getString("Make");
            textField_4.setText(Des);
             }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You get an error because you didn't replace the "?" in the SQL. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081941/jtable-fill-data-with-jcombobox/24083888#24083888 for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Statement you are using is for a prepared statement where you can add parameters.

You are using a normal statement execution where the ? is not replaced with an argument which results in a query that the sql server cannot understand.

You should look up PreparedStatement on how to use it (e.g. https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface)

Comment: Thanks for reply but now getting following error java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Select DeviceID,DeviceName,SerialNumber,ModelNumber,Make FROM deviceadd WHERE DeviceID =?");
       
      ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

Comment: You have to give the parameter. You want to get a specific device where the DeviceID has a specific value. Inside the SQL Query you have the ? and now you have to give the Parameter. Depending on the type, you have to call a function like setInt with parameter Index (starting at 1) and the value.

Inside the link I gave you are multiple examples.

Comment: thanks following Query solve my problem:      PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Select DeviceID,DeviceName,SerialNumber,ModelNumber,Make FROM deviceadd WHERE DeviceID ='"+textField.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");