# How to display data retrieved from database in a JTable?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

Can anybody help to retrieve data from database and put them into `JTable` by using `JButton`?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
       
public class try1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel Lsearch;                                            
    static JTable table;
    String column[]={"ID","NAME"};
    JTextField Tsearch;                                        
    //String driverName;
    JButton Bsearch;                                           
    //String url;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();         
    //String userName;String password;
    String id= "";
    String name= "";
    String textvalue;
    String sql;

    public try1() {

        Lsearch = new JLabel(" ID:");
        Tsearch = new JTextField(15);
        Bsearch = new JButton("SEARCH");

        //String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example";
        //String userName = "root";String password = "root";
        String id= "";
        String name= "";

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(column);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        textvalue = Tsearch.getText();

        add(scroll);add(Lsearch);add(Tsearch);add(Bsearch);
        Lsearch.setBounds(0, 0, 100,30);
        Tsearch.setBounds(30,3,100,20);
        Bsearch.setBounds(150,3,100,20);
        Bsearch.addActionListener(this);
        scroll.setBounds(0  , 100, 350, 50);

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new try1();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == Bsearch) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example", "root", "");
                sql = "select * from edata where ID = " + textvalue;
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    id = rs.getString("ID");
                    name = rs.getString("NAME");
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{id, name});
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Successfully Update", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } catch(Exception ei) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? what have you tried? what did go wrong? what exactly you have a problem in?

Comment: Where is the error? Did you execute the code in the ActionListener? Do you have data in the ResultSet? Do you have data in the TableModel? Do some basic debugging BEFORE asking a question and then ask a specific question after you have narrowed done the location of the error.   You are using the `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083888/131872 for an example.

Comment: Where is the error? Did you execute the code in the ActionListener? Do you have data in the ResultSet? Do you have data in the TableModel? Do some basic debugging BEFORE asking a question and then ask a specific question after you have narrowed done the location of the error.   You are using the `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083888/131872 for an example. Also, variable names should not start with an upper case character. However, class names SHOULD start with an upper case character.

Comment: `} catch(Exception ei) { System.out.println(""); }` </head-desk> Call `ei.printStackTrace()` in that catch body! **General tips:** 1) Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using ..

Comment: .. different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  **Instead** use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).