# Filtering in Java Swing Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

```
public void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<ListTable, Object> rf = null;
    //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);

}
```

I'm using this filter from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting
But this filter seems only able to filter int component on my table (Apart from the first col, all others are strings) . I simply want to create a Filter that leave any row with entered text. I'm relatively new to the language, Thanks very much for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxOmz.jpg
Here is 3 Image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable did you read this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: Wait, so your problem is that the filter is applied to the first column only?

Comment: Yes. The problem is Filter only apply to the 1st column
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable
doesnt seems to help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is explicitly applied to column zero, the first column. As shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter-java.lang.String-int...-), you can include *all* columns by omitting the `indices` parameter:

```
rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText());
```

Alternatively, you can include specified columns, e.g. columns one through three:

```
rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 1, 2, 3);
```

A related example that combines filters is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856131/230513).

Addendum: In helpful comments, @Ordous reminds me that correct usage hinges on the [*varargs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) feature, new in Java 5.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I clearly didn't understand the use of filters well.

Comment: I'd give a +1 since the answer is correct, but I really don't like questions that are solvable by just quoting the Javadoc on the method *already used* by the OP...

Comment: @Ordous: I tend to agree, but I also have a clear memory of stumbling over [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) when the feature was new to me.

Comment: @trashgod True, it can be confusing. But if it says "indices of values to check" on an argument you supply, and you have a problem with some values not being checked, then that's the first place to look, possibly after the regex itself.