# Listener to display the searched term in textfield in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Goodeve guys. I hope you can help me on this one. I have trouble setting up my listener.

What I wanted to do is for the data's on the JTable to update based on the text that I type in the textfield.

Here's the whole code for the textfield.

```
    nameTextField = new JTextField(20);
    nameTextField.setBounds(60, 80, 260, 30);
    nameTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String search = nameTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
            DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) spreadSheet.getModel();
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table);
            tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
            spreadSheet.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);
        }
    });
```

By the way, I am supposed to hard code the components and these lines don't also work on my code (or maybe I am missing something):

```
@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        String search = nameTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
            DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) spreadSheet.getModel();
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table);
            tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
            spreadSheet.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);
    }
```

Here's a picture of the output:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filterling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

look into this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989058/5790043

I think you should first set RowFilter and then set a RowSorter to the spreadSheet.

```java
        String search = nameTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
        if (e.getSource() == nameTextField) {
            DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) spreadSheet.getModel();
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table);
            
            tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
            spreadSheet.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);
        }
```

Also, could you provide the code of the listener?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code.